# php trim function trims extra Less-than/Greater-than signs

Tags: php

I have a question about the PHP trim function.
Consider the following:

```
$x= '<p>blah</p>';  
$x= trim(trim($x, '<p>'), '</p>');
echo htmlentities($x) . "<br />"; 

This works as expected and prints blah
```

.

```
$x= '<p><b>blah</b></p>';   
$x= trim(trim($x, '<p>'), '</p>');
echo htmlentities($x) . "<br />"; 

This prints b>blah</b
```

I'm not looking for other ways around this.
I do wonder why the trim function shows this behavior (stripping the extra Less-than/Greater-than sign).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at `strip_tags`? You can specify a whitelist of tags that should _not_ be removed.

Comment: see: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php#refsect1-function.trim-parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`trim` treats the 2nd argument as a list of characters that can be removed, not as a continuous string. This explains why `b` remains, but `<` and `>` are removed.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I thought it was a continuous string.

Answer (score 0):

This is a default behaviour of `trim` function. You expect it to trim the exact string, but second parameter is instead a list of characters and any of them will be trimmed if found at each side of the string.

You could use simple RegEx like this:

```
$x = preg_replace(array('#^<p>#i', '#</p>$#i'), '', $x);
```

Comment: Why would you use a regex for something `str_replace()` can do?

Comment: @crypticツ because replacing *all occurrences* and *one occurrence at start and end* of the string is different thing.